# WMDC won't detect mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, activesync, wmdc

Using Windows 7 Pro. Connect Windows Mobile 6.5 device USB. In Device Manager, I see the device (Microsoft USB Sync) under "Mobile devices" every time I connect the scanner. But WMDC won't connect.

I tried reinstalling WMDC, uninstalling the driver in Device Manager, changing the login for the 2 services, disabling the "Enable advanced network functions" on the device USB to PC setting, rebooting (warm and cold) the device, rebooting the computer. But nothing works. I always see the device in Device Manager, but WMDC never connect.

anyone has an idea what I can try to make it work?? I'm out of idea...

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Please try the trouble shooting at https://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/09/05/windows-mobile-device-center-wmdc-or-activesync-troubleshooting/ and the linked articles (ie http://web.archive.org/web/20120614233828/http://modernnomads.info/wiki/index.php?page=Windows+Mobile+Device+Center+Troubleshooting)

Comment: I find out that devices (with same O/S) from other manufacturers works fine. I tried 2 different devices from Datalogic, they doesn't connect with WMDC. I tried 2 old Symbol MC9600 and it works just fine, WMDC connect perfectly. I'm lost here.

Those Datalogic devices used to work perfectly with WMDC, even on my dev laptop using Win10 Pro

Comment: Did you read the article links I mentioned? A first approach is to switch the ActiveSync Connection on the device from using "Enhanced Network": Start > Settings > Connections tab > USB to PC icon.  Remove the checkmark in the box next to "Enable enhanced network functionality". BTW: Windows 10 does not support WMDC out-of-the-box normally.
WMDC uses a PPP connection between device and PC. There are many possible causes to stop that from working. You should really provide a log. BTW2: the old Symbols probaly do not offer this "Enhanced network functionality" option.